# Set Default value in field Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to set this by Fluent API and I`ve read documentation. There is HasDefaultValue() method should I use. But I can not write it, VS does not give me to do it
[image]

the code below from here [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations)

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .Property(b => b.Rating)
        .HasDefaultValue(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you have installed nuget package `Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore.SqlServer`. It has a dependency of `Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore.Relational` whixh has the `HasDefaultValue()` extension